# False option returning in np select?

Tags: python, pandas

I made this np select but AND operators don't work!

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2107], 'B': [76380700]})
cond = [(df["A"]==2107)|(df["A"]==6316)&(df['B']>=10000000)&(df['B']<=19969999),
    (df["A"]==2107)|(df["A"]==6316)&(df['B']>=1000000)&(df['B']<=99999999)]
choices    =["Return 1", "Return 2"]
df["C"] = np.select(cond, choices, default = df["A"])
```

NP select return  "Return 1" but correct option is "Return 2"

```
>>df["C"]
0    Return 1
```

Cause this line return false

```
>>df["B"]<=19969999
False
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Operator precedence handles `&` before `|` meaning that all of the ANDs in cond1 evaluate first to False which then gets ORed with `(df["A"]==2107)` which is True. Are you perhaps missing some parentheses?

Comment: @HenryEcker Thank you!! I just change the sequence to
`df['B']>=10000000)&(df['B']<=19969999)&(df["A"]==2107)|(df["A"]==6316)` 
and work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an operator precendence issue.  Here's what you wrote:

```
cond = [
    (df["A"]==2107) |
    (df["A"]==6316) &
    (df['B']>=10000000) &
    (df['B']<=19969999),

    (df["A"]==2107) |
    (df["A"]==6316) &
    (df['B']>=1000000) &
    (df['B']<=99999999)
]
```

Here's how that is interpreted:

```
cond = [
    (df["A"]==2107) |
    (
        (df["A"]==6316) &
        (df['B']>=10000000) &
        (df['B']<=19969999)
    ),

    (df["A"]==2107) |
    (
        (df["A"]==6316) &
        (df['B']>=1000000) &
        (df['B']<=99999999)
    )
]
```

You need parens around the "or" clause:

```
cond = [
    ( (df["A"]==2107) | (df["A"]==6316) ) &
        (df['B']>=10000000) &
        (df['B']<=19969999),

    ( (df["A"]==2107) | (df["A"]==6316) ) &
        (df['B']>=1000000) &
        (df['B']<=99999999)
    )
]
```

And, by the way, there is absolutely nothing wrong with writing the expressions like I did there.  Isn't it much more clear what's going on when it's spaced out like that?

Comment: thanks for your explanation! It really gets a lot clearer that way, I'm going to start using this indentation in my scripts! @Tim Roberts

Answer (score 0):

I think you were missing parenthesis for `(df["A"]==2107)|(df["A"]==6316)`. In your script, condition for *Return 1* was checking `(df["A"]==2107)|(df["A"]==6316))&(df['B']>=10000000)&(df['B']<=19969999)` which means *A==2107 OR (A ==  6316 & B... & B... )*. That's why np.select returns 'Returns 1', because it is True.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2107], 'B': [76380700]})
cond = [((df["A"]==2107)|(df["A"]==6316))&(df['B']>=10000000)&(df['B']<=19969999),
    (df["A"]==2107)|(df["A"]==6316)&(df['B']>=1000000)&(df['B']<=99999999)]
choices    =["Return 1", "Return 2"]
df["C"] = np.select(cond, choices, default = df["A"])
```